# How can I get this result in IBM DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

For example a I have two schemas: **SCHEMA_1** and **SCHEMA_2**. In **SHEMA_1** I have a table named *TABLE*. This table includes two fields: FIELD_1, FIELD_2. In TABLE in FIELD_1 I have some letters: A, B, C. FIELD_2 has tables' names of SCHEMA 2: TABLE_10, TABLE_20, TABLE_30.

**SCHEMA_2** includes three tables: *TABLE_10*, *TABLE_20*, *TABLE_30* with some numbers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbz8.png)

I have to write query to get maximum number of each table in SCHEMA_2. How can I get this result>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zNzp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table schema1.tableA
  (field_1    char(1),
   field_2    varchar(10)); 
insert into schema1.tableA
  values ('A','table_10'),
         ('B','table_20'),
         ('C','table_30');  

create table schema2.table_10
  (field_1    dec(5,0));
insert into schema2.table_10
  values (20), (30), (40);
create table schema2.table_20
  (field_1    dec(5,0));
insert into schema2.table_20
  values (6), (9), (12);
create table schema2.table_30
  (field_1    dec(5,0));
insert into schema2.table_30
  values (10), (15), (20);

with tmp (table_name, field_1) as (
  select 'table_10', max(field_1) from schema2.table_10
  union all
  select 'table_20', max(field_1) from schema2.table_20
  union all
  select 'table_30', max(field_1) from schema2.table_30)
select a.field_1, b.field_1
  from schema1.tableA a
    join tmp b on b.table_name = a.field_2;
```

If you have too many tables to make the above work, you can use a user defined function like this:

```
create or replace function MaxNbr
    (p_TableName      varchar(128),
     p_TableSchema    varchar(128))
  Returns dec(5,0)
  language sql
  not deterministic
  no external action
  reads sql data
  returns null on null input
  not fenced
begin
  declare l_stmt     varchar(1024);
  declare l_table    varchar(128);
  declare l_schema   varchar(128);
  declare l_result   dec(5,0);

  set l_table = replace(upper(p_TableName),'"','');
  set l_schema = replace(upper(p_TableSchema),'"',''); 
  set l_stmt = 'values (select max(field_1) from "' || l_schema || '"."' ||
               trim(l_table) || '") into ?';

  prepare S1 from l_stmt;
  allocate sql descriptor 'D1';
  describe S1 using sql descriptor 'D1';
  execute S1 into sql descriptor 'D1';
  get sql descriptor 'D1' value 1 l_result = data;
  deallocate sql descriptor 'D1';

  return l_result;
end;
```

This is necessary because you cannot use a variable for an identifier like a table name or schema name.

To use the user defined function, you can do something like this:

```
set schema schema1;
set path = udf_schema;

select field_1, MaxNbr(field_2, 'schema2') as field_2
  from tableA;
```

Comment: Thanks. But what can I do, if SCHEMA_2 includes more than 3 tables? For example 50 tables with same field.

Comment: You are going to have to write a UDF to get the quantity from a table. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to code a table name as a variable.

Comment: Make sure you protect against injection.